# Singleton class not shared between different modules in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, pycharm

I'm trying to implement a singleton pattern in Python to share a class between different modules. I'm experiencing some issues where the same instance is not being shared between different appearances of the singleton class.

Here is my code:

```
from some.module import SomeClass

class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]

class SomeClassFactory(metaclass=SingletonMeta):

    _data1 = None
    _data2 = None
    _some_class_instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_some_class_instance(cls):
        return cls._some_class_instance

    @classmethod
    def initialize_instance(cls, data1, data2):
        if not cls._some_class_instance:
            cls._some_class_instance = SomeClass(data1, data2)
            cls._data1 = data1
```

**Module 2 (some.services):**

```
from typing import Optional, List
from some.factories import SomeClassFactory

class SomeClassService:

    def get_some_class_instance(self):
        factory = SomeClassFactory()
        return factory.get_some_class_instance()
```

**Testing on Python Console:**

```
from some.factories import SomeClassFactory
factory = SomeClassFactory()
factory.initialize_instance(data1, data2)
some_instance = factory.get_some_class_instance()

from some.services import SomeClassService
service_class = SomeClassService()
some_instance_2 = service_class.get_some_class_instance()  # Returns None
```

The expected behaviour is that `some_instance` and `some_instance_2` would refer to the same instance of `SomeClass`. However, `some_instance_2` is None.

The current issue I am facing is specific to PyCharm's python console. When I run the code outside of PyCharm, the singleton pattern works as expected, and `some_instance_2` correctly refers to the shared instance of SomeClass. However, when running inside PyCharm's python console, `some_instance_2` returns None.

I am using Python 3.9.7 as my version, and it seems that this issue is related to PyCharm's python console itself.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with PyCharm's python console and the singleton pattern? Is there a known workaround or configuration that can resolve this issue?

Comment: I have created two modules and placed the `SomeClassFactory` and `SomeClassService` classes to import them from the third - main module, but I am unable to reproduce the issue as it works for me. What version of Python do you currently use? (me: Python 3.9.7)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to solve the issue, and it appears that the problem lies within PyCharm's python console. When I run the code outside of PyCharm, everything works fine. I'm using Python 3.9.7 as my version.

Comment: Glad to know you have solved your problem. Thanks for sharing what the problem was.